# How to avoid polar bear in Antarctica?

Tags: safety, nature-and-wildlife, extreme-tourism, antarctica

I would like to visit Antarctica, but worry polar bear may chase after me.

How to avoid being attacked by polar bear?

Comment: Good news, there are no polar bears in Antarctica. Closing as unfortunately not useful to future travellers.

Comment: I would rather edit this question to correct name error than close it. Funny comments OK.

Comment: It's welcomed for the OP to edit a question and flag for reopening - we would be happy to consider them.

Comment: In fact not only the OP is allowed to edit the question. But just changing Antarctic to Arctic wouldn't be enough to save this particular question - in fact it would do better on great-outdoors.SE but would also need to be a lot more specific to fit the "one good answer" requirement of SE.

Comment: @KMC, Toni Frankola, lechlukasz.  As hippietrail points out there's still a bit of work to be done.  It's also not a travel problem as such - more an outdoors problem.  KMC, you flagged this stating it's not a joke and that you do indeed plan to visit Antarctica but worry about polar bears. This is after we've already told you there are NO polar bears there?  Really? Are you sure you mean Antarctica (south pole area) and not maybe the Arctic (north pole) where polar bears actually exist?  If so we can edit it to that and reopen or migrate.

Comment: @KMC, it was closed as too localised (specific), but there were also votes for non-constructive AND off-topic, so just changing the title won't be enough to reopen it, yet.  But we're here to help, so if you read the above paragraph and can act on that, we can look to getting you some answers :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are no Polar Bears in Antarctica, except for at Zoos.

There are also no Zoos in Antarctica.

So all up, you're pretty safe.

Comment: `you're pretty safe` OP still should beware of crafty penguins

Comment: Yes going to Antarctica is possibly one of the very best ways to avoid attack from a polar bear.

Comment: How about penguins disguised as polar bears?

Comment: There's no polar bears in Antarctica *now*, but who's to say they won't get there before he does? :)