# How to get to Antarctica without using a travel company

Tags: antarctica

I have a dream of skiing across the Antarctica continent. After some research it seems there is no scheduled flight to Antarctica, and the tours out there just reach the entrance of Antarctica and come back.

The question is how do the people who cross Antarctica get there?

Comment: You seem very unexperienced for something like this. Please stop that suicidal plan until you had some years time to get experience. ... I bet the company mentioned below will plainly refuse to take you there anyways even if you have the money, until you make it believable you're prepared, but still that has to be said here.

Comment: Like ... ski 1000km through Russian winter without entering any heated house, and of course start smaller first, and learn some medics, navigation plus emergency contact things, handling/avoiding/eating wildlife (including those of Antartica), ... Do it again. Go up some Himalaya glacier. etc.etc. ... Get permission from some country. ... And don't forget preparing your things at home for your death, because even with the best preparation it's still an extreme plan you have there.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99891/discussion-on-question-by-moses-kim-how-to-get-to-antarctica-without-using-a-tra).

Comment: Just remember to keep an eye out for Polar Bears whilst you are there - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7821/how-to-avoid-polar-bear-in-antarctica

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Companies such as [Antarctica Logistics](https://antarctic-logistics.com/destination/expeditions/) provide transport to and from the continent. Prices in general appear quite high.

I would suggest doing multiple long ski tours before attempting this, for somewhat obvious reasons...

Comment: "Prices in general appear quite high" could use a rough order of magnitude to make this less fo a link-only answer.

Comment: @R.. roughly $25,000 - $65,000 for [trips](https://antarctic-logistics.com/trip-finder/#view=grid) with Ski trips starting at [around $30K](https://antarctic-logistics.com/trip/ski-antarctica/).

Comment: Guys there is ***no way*** you could get there "not on a tour" for that little money.  Just FYI those prices are for a tour group visit (probably 20-50 folks at a time.)

Comment: @Fattie Realistically, the OP could get away from the coast, for a much lower cost than a private expedition, by doing e.g. a ski the last degree tour (ski from 89 south to the pole). The very fact that it is a group activity, with experienced organizers, makes it much safer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - I guess, but .. ?  The question is absolutely specifically how not to take a tour!

Answer (score 16):

Couldn't be easier.

You just hire a plane (I mean "a private plane charter") to fly you there, and another one to fly you back from the other side.

[image]

Any jet charter in NZ will do it, and any number of companies do it enough they actually have Google-Ad-Words web sites for the function.

Simply google "private jet charter, NZ to Antartica".

Or phone any major jet charter company in NZ (or perhaps Tasmania, or just Melbourne - I mean what the hell is the odd thousand miles one way or the other here?) and ask for a price for the two legs.

My guess is it would actually cost *less* to hire a jet than to have a boat/ship of some type take you on both legs.

I'd guess the cost of two such jet rentals would be perhaps around $150,000 all-up.

(The tiny figures mentioned elsewhere, 20 grand etc, are almost certainly for a tour of some 10-30 I'd guess people, and it seems OP does not want a tour-bus approach - and fair enough!)

It's very easy to get to Antartica, you just rent a jet - in answer to your question.

---

## Has anyone ever crossed Antartica *solo* ?

It looks like yes, a couple different blokes have arguably done this:

https://explorersweb.com/2018/12/27/obradys-antarctic-crossing-was-it-really-unassisted/

It takes two months.

Interesting, there is a HUGE difference and debate between *unsupported* and *unassisted* in the Exploration Thrills world.

## Has anyone actually *"crossed"* Antartica anyway ?

NOTE that these dudes took the **shortest imaginable route "across" (ROFL)** Antartica:

[image: descrip]

OP, the field is wide open to be the first to actually go "across" Antartica.

Godspeed.

Actually it looks like a Norwegian bloke, Borge Ousland, actually did it properly without using roads back in the 90s.

[image]

*Random photo of impossibly rugged Norwegian Borge Ousland who did what OP asks about.*

Seems he ingeniously used a kite where possible, like ski-kiteing.

Comment: it's cheaper to get a boat from "The End of the World" (Ushuaia) in Argentina

Comment: @AaronF , I really don't think that's the case.  Hiring a small boat (like, "a 50 foot sailboat" when you hire a yacht for a few weeks in the Caribbean for a holiday) is pretty expensive, but hiring a largish ship is an expensive business.  You'd be talking about chartering a whole ship and crew for weeks, maybe months - very expensive. Ships cost millions.

Comment: it's about $5000 https://mundoexplora.com/descubriendo-la-antartida-bordo-del-ushuaia/ OP might be able to get a discount for only needing to travel one-way ;-)

Comment: (oh, now I notice the bit where OP discounts a cruise, because they only barely touch Antarctica before coming back; ok then you win ;-P )

Comment: Right, I hear you, it's a confusing question because there are many "canned solutions" to just *have a look at* Antartica.  (For example, I believe for those living in Aussie, it's pretty common to take a "scenic flight over Antartica" where someone has a jumbo jet they simply fly down there on clear days with 300 people for a couple grand each ...)

Comment: I read about people sailing on a yacht to Antarctica. As I learned from school the waves at  60°S is very strong. Are these people risking there lives or is it just me knowing the wrong thing?

Comment: @MosesKim , you should ask a different question about "sailing Southern seas" (perhaps on a sailing web site, may not be relevant here)

Comment: Note that some of the websites that show up when you do the search have just automatically created pages for all airfields in the world. One of them actually says you can land at an airfield that has been closed for years. Also, remember that all but one of the airfields in Antarctica are snow, ice or blue ice, and are not suitable for just any type of aircraft (some will not accept wheeled aircraft, for instance, or only propellers). Of course, many of just not open year round due to weather conditions (which may be counter-intuitive, due to melting in the summer).

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure there are many companies that provide flights "to Antarctica" which actually only do an overfly and then turn back. Actually landing there can be quite a challenge. If you don't see a picture of an aircraft actually on the snow/ice on their website, you can most probably skip it.

Comment: JC - if you phone an actual large-aircraft charter company, they understand that stuff  :)